# Please help me identify this language (image)

Tags: written-language, writing-systems, writing

I found this inscription on something I recently purchased, not sure what it is. Can you please help identify it?

[image: Inscription]

Comment: I think it is upside-down and it's either Tamil or Malayalam. I can't read either language, so I'm not sure. What is the object, and where did you buy it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about identifying language.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

@prash is right, that is Malayalam, and the text is upside down, it reads "mādhavi", മാധവി, which is most likely a female name.

Comment: Not enough reputation to comment (but definitely comment material). As @Yellow Sky mentioned it says mādhavi which, on the [Malayalam Wikipedia](http://ml.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E0%B4%AE%E0%B4%BE%E0%B4%A7%E0%B4%B5%E0%B4%BF) refers to the mononymous actress. And a link to the translated article on the [English Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madhavi_(actress)). I just thought it was interesting.